# Files.move works fine with MAC OS but giving below error in Windows machine

Tags: java, macos, file, io

I am moving a directory from one path to another path. I'm using the following code to do that

```
import java.nio.*;    
Path temp = Files.move(Paths.get("/user/vinayak/source"),Paths.get("/user/vinayak/destination")
                     , StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
```

Destination directory is creating at runtime. It works fine on a MAC machine but when I tried it on Windows then I'm getting the following error

```
java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: /user/vinayak/source -> /user/vinayak/destination        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:90)
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:111)
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixCopyFile.move(UnixCopyFile.java:478)
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.move(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:267)
        at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.move(Files.java:1422)
        at scripts.DataMigratorScript.performImport(DataMigratorScript.java:234)
        at scripts.DataMigratorScript.main(DataMigratorScript.java:78)
```

Comment: Unix style paths ` /user/vinayak/...` and Unix file system `UnixFileSystemProvider` is strange on Windows. WSL?

Comment: I'd rather use [this](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Paths.html#get(java.lang.String,java.lang.String...))